# Tests using FakeApplication unexpectedly freeze Play 2.1-RC2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

I have a simple test like this:

```
  "xxx" should {
    "xxx" in running(FakeApplication()) {
    route(
      FakeRequest(GET, "/xxx/xxxx")
    ) must beLike {
    case Some(result) => {
      "" must_== ""
    }
  }
```

The test always freezes near the end of the test:

```
...
[info] Total for test controllers.XxxTest
[info] Finished in 0.001 seconds
[info] 1 tests, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

So I quit the test Ctrl+C...

Is there any Idea?

---

JVM 1.7.0_11
Scala 2.10.0
Play 2.1-RC2
Mac OSX 10.8.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that they re-enabled forking of tests (see https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/654). So you need to upgrade sbt to 0.12.2-RC2, by simply putting

```
sbt.version=0.12.2-RC2
```

into your `build.properties`.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary measures

Add the following snippet in your Build.scala (or Build.sbt):

```
sbt.Keys.fork in Test := false
```